# calling a ruby file from a RakeFile

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm creating an application which requires migrations without rails. For that I have created a rake file to execute commands.

My problem is how can I call a ruby class function from a rake file. I want something like this. consider both are in the same directory

> class A
>
> def b
>
> ```
> puts 'calling method B from class A'
> ```
>
> end
>
> end

in the RakeFile

> task :create do
>
> A.new.b
>
> end

I want to execute it as

> rake create

But currently I'm getting this error

> rake aborted!
>
> no such file to load -- a

I'm using ruby 1.9.1, rake (0.8.7)

thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 3):

Have you required the file containing the class? Meaning, have you used any statement like

```
require "path/to/a.rb" #where a.rb contains the class A
```

It seems like ruby converter unable to find where to look for class A.